# C# How do disable a key

Tags: c#, events, key

How do I prevent the caret going to the next line in a text box when the 'ENTER' key has been pressed? In other words how to disable the 'ENTER' or 'RETURN' key in a text-box?

Answer (score 12):

You can write the `OnKeyDown` event. you can use the `e.SuppressKeyPress` to tell .NET that you handle the key. Something like this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for useful information for the general case even if it's not the best approach for this particular scenario

Comment: WOW fast reply... this is way better than other forums (don't want to say which ones) where people insult people who ask questions.

Thanks, thanks.

Comment: KeyPressEventArgs doesn't contains SuppressKeyPress... I am using OnKeyPress event

Comment: If you want to suppress de key you would have to use OnKeyDown

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `TextBox.AcceptsReturn`.

Comment: is there a way to do this on a richtextbox?

Comment: I am afraid not. But you can override OnKeyDown as Jedi Master Spooky suggests.