# Preventing form to do things

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want my Form `frmMainMenu` to disable stuffs. the first thing I did is set it to `maximized` and remove the `minimize & maximize` on control. When I drag the form it automatically `minimized`, also when I double click the `controlBox` it also `minimize`. I also want the form to prevent `movement`. and lastly i want to disable the `alt + tab` on my form.

I have some code here for disabling movement.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
        switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

here is for double click

```
 private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3; 

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

i dont have a code for `drag` and `alt + tab` and i cant put those two in my form because the have the same parameter `WndProc`.

Comment: Disable what 'stuffs' ? Be specific.

Comment: is that not specific? disable drag, doubleclick, alt +tab and prevent movement?

Comment: No very clear at least. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements

Comment: Very user-hostile, surely there's another way to accomplish whatever you are trying to achieve.  If this is some kind of kiosk app then there are much better ways to lock down the machine.

Comment: im using c#. new to programing, dont know anything about kiosk app. I just want the form to be ontop of the windows that only one button can close it.

Comment: In that case you might want to use the Form.ShowDialog method to show the form. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx  This will limit the scope of the action to your own application. Capturing and denying access to standard windows actions is against almost every design guidelines, unless you're trying to build your own ATM user-interface or a UI for a cash register (these are generally called Kiosk apps).

Comment: my form is an mdi dont need to open another form im opening form inside toolstripcontainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Create a `Form`
2. Set `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle`
3. Set `MinimizeBox` to `false`
4. Set `MaximizeBox` to `false`
5. Set `TopMost` to `true`
6. Handle `Load`, `FormClosing` and `DeActivate` events of your form.
7. Write this code in your form class:

**Code:**

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }
    //System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input  
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
    //Declaring Global objects     
    private IntPtr ptrHook;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

    private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            // Disabling Windows keys 

            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Tab && HasAltModifier(objKeyInfo.flags) || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Escape && (ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1; // if 0 is returned then All the above keys will be enabled
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
    }

    bool HasAltModifier(int flags)
    {
        return (flags & 0x20) == 0x20;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
        objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(captureKey);
        ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

        switch (message.Msg)
        {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                    return;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- The code for disable <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> has taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3227562/3110834), Thanks to the author.
- The code for preventing move, has taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907868/3110834), Thanks to the author.
- Don't Forgt to add usings:

**Usings:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: alt + tab not working `marshal` does not exist,`process` does not exist, `DllImport` coul not be found  etc also i cant add `WndProc` because i got 2 of the same type how should i join this three together?

Comment: @anjohnnette Glad to hear that it worked. It's funny that when I was testing to post changes that you requested in previous comment, the form stayed at top in maximized state and I couldn't get rid of it and at last I restarted my laptop using power button! :))

Comment: haha sorry :) i remove `e.cancel = true` so that i can use the x button on `controlbox`