# Form that locks UI

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I've created an app in Visual C# with a Form.

I need that form must be always on top and fullscreen (of course, center).
The users must be submit the form to use computer (no Alt+F4, no ALT+TAB).

I tried to set the TopMost property to "True" and I set the form to fullscreen (but the contents remain on the top-left corner, like initial dimensions, and the user can switch between app with keyboard).

Is that possible? Essentially I want a lockscreen.

Thank you!

Comment: What should happen if two different programs both set their form to topmost? - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

Comment: To build a lock screen, build a lock screen, but this is hard work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The later one wins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding disabling <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>:
[How to Disable Alt + F4 closing form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943/how-to-disable-alt-f4-closing-form)

Regarding full-screen:
[How to display a Windows Form in full screen on top of the taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272019/how-to-display-a-windows-form-in-full-screen-on-top-of-the-taskbar)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and others):
[How to Suppress task switch keys (winkey, alt-tab, alt-esc, ctrl-esc) using low-level keyboard hook in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213606/how-to-suppress-task-switch-keys-winkey-alt-tab-alt-esc-ctrl-esc-using-low)

Regarding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>, it's not possible to disable. However, as stated elsewhere, you may want to consider IE Kiosk mode.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/154780